# batch file that uses a sql query to find files that it needs to move and moves them

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

Is it possible to create a batch file that calls a SQL query (saved as files_to_move.SQL) and uses the results (which are all names of folders on the pc) as input for a copy command?

All I have thus far is running the .SQL file in CMD:

```
sqlcmd -S FREIGHTFLOW -i C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Reports\Source\no_read_images_locations.sql
```

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am stuck at the beginning and hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  At this point all I have is a SQL query that identifies all the files that meet my criteria.  Will update my question to show this.